# Replace commas with single quotes

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a parameter being passed to a stored procedure.  The value of the parameter looks like this:

0001,0002,0003

I need for it to look like this:

'0001','0002','0003'

I've tried several ways of escaping the single quotes in the Replace function, but the MySQL Workbench keeps giving me syntax errors.

```
replace(AccountNumber, ',', '\',\'');
```

```
replace(AccountNumber, ',', '','');
```

I get an 'Unexpected' syntax error on the find text and an 'Unexpected' syntax error on the replace with text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? This kinda sounds like an XY problem. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you have, what you are trying to and what the problems are. Also add the full SQL statements you are trying to execute and the full error messages you get.

Comment: The first version should work. You can also use double quotes in MySQL: `REPLACE(AccountNumber, ",", "','")`

Comment: If you're doing this to create dynamic SQL, it's probably not necessary. You can probably do what you want using `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT( "'"
        ,REPLACE('0001,0002,0003',',',"','")
        , "'");
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT CONCAT( "'",REPLACE('0001,0002,0003',',',"','"), "'");
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT( "'",REPLACE('0001,0002,0003',',',"','"), "'") |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| '0001','0002','0003'                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first syntax is correct; something else in your statement that you don't show is wrong.  Though you will also want to add single quotes around the whole thing:

```
select concat('\'',replace(AccountNumber, ',', '\',\''),'\'')
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=144c637bebca071efadde484d3e7a2d6).

You might find it more convenient to use double quotes:

```
select concat("'",replace(AccountNumber, ',', "','"),"'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This data is coming from a SSRS report, which I do not have access to, otherwise I would modify it there.

My issue, as it turns out, was that I just had the Replace statement appearing on a line, I wasn't setting the returned value to a variable.  So once I added

```
Set @AccntNo = CONCAT("'", Replace(....), "'");
```

The syntax errors went away.  But @[Bernd Buffen] and @ysth had it right.